# Accordion Body One to stay always open when manually close all bodies

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I want my accordion to automatically open the first item body by manually closing the all bodies in accordion

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    $('#accordionExample').each(function(i){
        $(this).on("click" ,{value:i},function(event){
            var allCollapsed = true;
            $('.accordion-item').each(function() {
                if ($(this).find('.collapse').length > 0) {
                    allCollapsed = false;
                    return false;
                }                        
            });

            if(allCollapsed==true)
            {
                alert("ban");
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: `$('#accordionExample').each` is likely the first mistake as IDs must be unique - so `$('#accordionExample').length` will always be 0 or 1.